# Create a memory game using JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

### Problem

I can't figure out an good algorithm that only allows me to have two selected buttons at the same time with the switched image. If the switched images is the same on the two buttons I want to hide them. If not I want them to return to their original image that I use when the card is faced down (smiley face). I use an start class that open up my JPanel in a JFrame. 
I'm not a native speaker so I hope I made myself clear.

### Code

```
public class MemoryMain extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private ImageIcon iconStart = new ImageIcon ("images\\smiley.jpg");
    private ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon ("images\\amazed.jpg");
    private ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon ("images\\datass.jpg");
    private ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon ("images\\lol.jpg");
    private ImageIcon icon4 = new ImageIcon ("images\\megusta.jpg");
    private ImageIcon icon5 = new ImageIcon ("images\\mog.png");
    private ImageIcon icon6 = new ImageIcon ("images\\satisfied.jpg");
    private JButton btn1 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn2 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn3 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn4 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn5 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn6 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn7 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn8 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn9 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn10 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn11 = new JButton ();
    private JButton btn12 = new JButton ();
    private ImageIcon[] iconArray = new ImageIcon[12];

    public MemoryMain () {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension (800, 600));
        setBackground (Color.CYAN);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4));

        btn1.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn2.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn3.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn4.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn5.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn6.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn7.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn8.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn9.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn10.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn11.setIcon(iconStart);
        btn12.setIcon(iconStart);

        btn1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn10.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn11.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));
        btn12.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (80,80));

        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);
        btn4.addActionListener(this);
        btn5.addActionListener(this);
        btn6.addActionListener(this);
        btn7.addActionListener(this);
        btn8.addActionListener(this);
        btn9.addActionListener(this);
        btn10.addActionListener(this);
        btn11.addActionListener(this);
        btn12.addActionListener(this);

        add(btn1);
        add(btn2);
        add(btn3);
        add(btn4);
        add(btn5);
        add(btn6);
        add(btn7);
        add(btn8);
        add(btn9);
        add(btn10);
        add(btn11);
        add(btn12);
        this.iconArray = randomArray();

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        if (e.getSource() == btn1) {
            Image temp = iconArray[0].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn1.setIcon(icon);

        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn2) {
            Image temp = iconArray[1].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn2.setIcon(icon);

        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn3) {
            Image temp = iconArray[2].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn3.setIcon(icon);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn4) {
            Image temp = iconArray[3].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn4.setIcon(icon);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn5) {
            Image temp = iconArray[4].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn5.setIcon(icon);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn6) {
            Image temp = iconArray[5].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn6.setIcon(icon);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn7) {
            Image temp = iconArray[6].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn7.setIcon(icon);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn8) {
            Image temp = iconArray[7].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn8.setIcon(icon);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn9) {
            Image temp = iconArray[8].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn9.setIcon(icon);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn10) {
            Image temp = iconArray[9].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn10.setIcon(icon);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn11) {
            Image temp = iconArray[10].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn11.setIcon(icon);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btn12) {
            Image temp = iconArray[11].getImage();
            Image resizedImage = temp.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
            btn12.setIcon(icon);

        }

    }
    public ImageIcon[] randomArray () {
        iconArray[0] = icon1;
        iconArray[1] = icon1;
        iconArray[2] = icon2;
        iconArray[3] = icon2;
        iconArray[4] = icon3;
        iconArray[5] = icon3;
        iconArray[6] = icon4;
        iconArray[7] = icon4;
        iconArray[8] = icon5;
        iconArray[9] = icon5;
        iconArray[10] = icon6;
        iconArray[11] = icon6;

        for (int i = iconArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int j = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            ImageIcon temp = iconArray[i];
            iconArray[i] = iconArray[j];
            iconArray[j] = temp;
        }
        return iconArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: If first click store the last e.getsource() in second click compare to current click and reset the last source to 0 (first click again)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you don't use arrays. You are dealing with 12 `btn__` fields for the buttons and with 6 `icon_` fields for the icons. When you wrote the `actionPerformed()` method you should realize "There must be an easier way than to check `btn1` to `btn12`". And the answers are "arrays".

Save all the icons in an array so you can easily use them. Save all the buttons in an array as well so you can easily use them as well. When you have this you can use simple an easy array index access to access the correct icon or button. Maybe you can use an additional array to save the information which cards are faced up or faced down. Or maybe even create a new class `Card` which has the field `picture` for the icon when faced up  and a boolean field `isFacedUp` to save if this card is currently faced up or down.